# debuggging eclipse plugin dependancy

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dependencies

I am creating an eclipse plugin that calls some classes from a Java project. I have added this Java project as a required project on my build path.
When I create an eclipse plugin jar using an ant script, everything works fine.
However when I try to debug the code at run time or open the eclipse as a run time application, the classes from the Java project are not accessible. I get a NoClassDefFoundException.

Is there something I am missing while adding the dependancy?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is based on OSGi, and as a rule of thumb, bundles can only see other bundles.  Usually for including 3rd party jars in an eclipse plugin, you have 2 choices:

1) Include the jar in your eclipse project.  Add it to the **build.properties**.  Edit the **MANIFEST.MF** and add it to the *Classpath* section on the *Runtime* tab.

2) turn the 3rd party jar into a bundle so that your eclipse plugin can require it.  You can use *File>New>Other...>Plug-in Development>Plug-in from Existing JAR*.  The simplest form of an OSGi bundle is just the original jar with OSGi headers added to its **MANIFEST.MF**.

**EDIT:**

Remember also you have to honour the 3rd party jar license with whichever option you choose.